# Master-Detail Application - Show master view at the right of the application not left

Tags: ios, xcode, master-detail

The master detail application shows the master view controller at the left of the application,which is perfect for English data entries and handling.
But if i want to show the master view at the right of the application, in a Right-To-Left kind of way, suitable for Arabic entries, how can i change the position of the master view and force it to load from the right side of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with `UISplitViewController`.

There is better alternative [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) By Matt Gemmel. Its API's are very similar to UISplitViewController, so that you can easily migrate to it. You can toggle Master and detail views vertically and horizontally.
It has other very nice features also like draggable divider etc.

Comment: thank you for your time :) it's a bit of unfortunate to redo one more project from scratch :S

Comment: Just want to concern you that MGSplitViewController wasn't updated for 3 years and may contain some hidden edge cases (i.e. unexpected behaviour) in iOS 7. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As of **iOS 11** this is possible with a property called `UISplitViewControllerPrimaryEdge` we can set the `PrimaryEdge` to either `Leading` or `Trailing` as like below.

```
self.splitViewController.primaryEdge = UISplitViewControllerPrimaryEdgeTrailing;
self.splitViewController.primaryEdge = UISplitViewControllerPrimaryEdgeLeading;
```